# Can I eliminiate viewmodel and viewbinding boilerplate code in my Android Fragments?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-viewmodel, boilerplate, android-viewbinding

I find myself writing boilerplate code for each new fragment I create.
this includes setting up the viewmodel and viewbinding, these are 2 different parts of my code that don't rely on eachother, so a solution for one of them will be still be great.

Fragment code example:

```
class MyFragment : Fragment() {

    // View binding
    private var _binding: FragmentMyBinding? = null

    // View model
    private lateinit var model : MyViewModel

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        // Model init
        model = ViewModelProvider(this).get(MyViewModel::class.java)

        //binding init
        _binding = FragmentMyBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)

        return _binding!!.root
    }

}

class MyViewModel : ViewModel()
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As seen on the [ViewModel documentation page](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel), Kotlin code should not use `ViewModelProvider(this)`, but instead use [`by viewModels()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/fragment/app/package-summary#viewmodels) which is part of the `fragment-ktx` dependency. This replaces the `lateinit var model` usage and having to do anything in `onCreateView()`, meaning with just that, your fragment becomes:

```
class MyFragment : Fragment() {

    // View binding
    private var _binding: FragmentMyBinding? = null

    // View model
    private val model: MyViewModel by viewModels()

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        //binding init
        _binding = FragmentMyBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)

        return _binding!!.root
    }
}
```

You can follow an approach such as [this one](https://evan.tatarka.me/2020/03/02/you-dont-need-to-null-out-views.html) and avoid holding onto the binding at all. This approach would mean your fragment would be:

```
class MyFragment : Fragment(R.layout.my_fragment) {

    // View model
    private val model: MyViewModel by viewModels()

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        val binding = FragmentMyBinding.bind(view)
        // Now use the binding and your ViewModel
    }
}
```

One other option is to copy [`AutoClearedValue`](https://github.com/android/architecture-components-samples/blob/master/GithubBrowserSample/app/src/main/java/com/android/example/github/util/AutoClearedValue.kt) into your project and use it, which would instead make it look like:

```
class MyFragment : Fragment() {

    // View binding
    private var binding by autoCleared<FragmentMyBinding>()

    // View model
    private val model: MyViewModel by viewModels()

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        binding = FragmentMyBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
        // Now use the binding and your ViewModel

        return binding.root
    }
}
```

At this point, with either solution, you're using at most 3 shared lines of code, all of which are different so trying to build a base fragment and dealing with generics is going to make things more complicated than not and would be something I would not suggest.